# Using reporting to show field completeness

Tags: reporting, dashboard

I have an object with a bunch of fields and I want to run a report that will show the total number of records and how many or what percentage of each field is complete

Answer (score 2):

There's really no report that can do this directly, but [RingLead's Field Trip](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003HSXEEA4) app can do this for you. This is a Free app.

Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated with RingLead. Always do your own product research and test in a sandbox to see if a product meets your needs.